# What is an optimum size for an Android app?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

My app is around 1.5MB at the moment. Is that on the higher size?

What is the average size for an Android app and is there an upper limit placed on it by Google?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know about the average or optimum size of an apk file but an apk file of or upto 50 MB is currently supported. As per the Android Market for Developer Help;

> **APK file size:** Maximum supported size is 50MB.

Source: [Android Market for Developer Help](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=113469)

**Update (06 March 2012):**

As of 05 March 2012, by using the new concept of [APK Expansion File](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html), an app (not an APK) can be as big as 4GB. See the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the official link. That is something I can confidently show to the business :)

Comment: @Faisal: I know, thats why I posted the answer even I was late to answer. Thanks for accepting. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is upper limit in android app market. I have downloaded 25+MB applications without problem.

1.5MB is just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the reputability of [this site](http://androidcommunity.com/android-market-upgrading-app-size-limit-to-4gb-20110511/), but the current limit is 50MB and will soon be 4 GB.

Although 1.5 MB is still pretty small in comparison, I would recommend optimizing as well as possible. People still have to download this and the sooner they have it the happier they are.

Comment: Google will store two files (in addition to the original 50MB) of data per application at no additional cost. The maximum file size for each of these two files is 2GB. http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2481797