# Reduce apk size with combine java files

Tags: android, size, apk

Does reducing number of .java files reduces apk size?
For example is it better that i define my `ListAdapter` inside `Activity` class rather than a separate .java file?

What about xml files? for example make a `shape.xml` and reference it in `selector.xml` or define that shape inside the `item` of selector?

Comment: Inner classes are generated as separate class files once compiled so I don't think it makes a huge difference. I am not sure if having one huge xml instead of few small ones would have any impact on the size of apk as well.

Comment: sorry but i have some critical situation and even small size changes are very important (such as ~5kb)
are you saying that this should not be my concern?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, no.  If you're concerned about ensuring the smallest size for your apk, I'd make use of Android lint's unused resources tool.  Additionally, pay attention to the file sizes of your image resources as these typically contribute the most to apk bloat.

Comment: most size is consumed by images/videos/audios in large apks so you should be focusing on that. refer to http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175849/what-is-an-optimum-size-for-an-android-app

Comment: @MichaelKrause thanks, i think i should read about the way java compiler compile my codes

Answer (score 3):

> Does reducing number of .java files reduces apk size?

Not in general.

> What about xml files? for example make a shape.xml and reference it in selector.xml or define that shape inside the item of selector?

That might save a handful of bytes.

> i have some critical situation and even small size changes are very important (such as ~5kb)

Then [reduce your APK size](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/):

- Get rid of libraries where you are using tiny pieces of them, and use the minimum possible library set (e.g., specific pieces of Play Services, not the whole "kitchen sink" Play Services library)
- Reduce the number of density variants of your drawables, if in testing the automatic resampling by Android meets your needs, and use Lint to identify resources that might be lingering in your project that you are not referencing
- Use ProGuard
- Use `minifyResources` and `resConfigs` options in your Gradle build file, if you are using Android Studio
- And everything else Cyril Mottier points out in that blog post

Answer (score 0):

you better to reduce image resources, and if you are using maven/gradle build system you can reduce apk size by shirking the code using progaurd tool .

Answer (score 0):

APK Size:

Generally it depends on the assets you have used. Try using LINT in android studio, which give you a summary of unused resources, which you can check and delete.

Also, proguard is very helpful in this, try using proguard in your application.

http://dominoc925.blogspot.in/2015/01/enabling-proguard-obfuscation-in.html

use minifyenabled = true with following proguard basic configuration I found somewhere on Stackoverflow :

```
-dontwarn org.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

# Remove Logging statements
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.antew.redditinpictures.library.imgur.** { *; }
-keep class com.antew.redditinpictures.library.reddit.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

#QuickBlox
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smackx.** { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class * implements org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.SmackDebugger { public *; }
```